# How to use arrayformula to indicate an occurrence in google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to write an =arrayformula that finds the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. occurrence of a value in another column. I can do this with a formula copied down all rows but I don't want to use this method, I need the arrayformula to simply always update the column because I need to constantly insert and delete rows and I don't want to have to keep copying the formula down. Thanks in advance.

[Google sheet where I'm testing this.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XRxHFulmB8rKgK64yzNbPRSBAJ4lXHm-6t0Aig55iLI/edit?usp=sharing)

Example formulas that I currently have to copy down..I want this to simply be an arrayformula instead:

values |    occurance

aa      |   =if(A3<>"",countif($A$3:$A3,A3),"") | RESULT:1

2      |    =if(A4<>"",countif($A$3:$A4,A4),"") | RESULT:1

aa      |   =if(A5<>"",countif($A$3:$A5,A5),"") | RESULT:2

5      |    =if(A6<>"",countif($A$3:$A6,A6),"") | RESULT:1

5      |    =if(A7<>"",countif($A$3:$A7,A7),"") | RESULT:2

4      |    =if(A8<>"",countif($A$3:$A8,A8),"") | RESULT:1

[Formulas that work but have to be copied down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dAn4.png)

Comment: SO suggested it and seemed appropriate in the event someone can offer excel example that would be applicable or similar enough to get me somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out cell D3 where I used this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(A3:A),SORT(ROW(A3:A),A3:A,1),1)-MATCH(A3:A,SORT(A3:A),0)-ROW()+2))
```

and see if that works for you ?